# I couldn't understand the source code of Humidity & Temperature Sensor using RaspberryPi

Tags: c, raspberry-pi

I was trying to understand the meanings and rules of this code which is humidity and temperture module.
I want run it with C and RaspberryPi.
However even though I tried to figure this out, I don't understand what ***** part is doing.

Why MAXTIMINGS is 85?
Why if sentence compare to 255?
Could you tell me someone what the meaning of **** part is?

Here is a timing chart and datasheet link.

([https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/758/DHT11-Technical-Data-Sheet-Translated-Version-1143054.pdf#search='DHT11+datasheet'](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/758/DHT11-Technical-Data-Sheet-Translated-Version-1143054.pdf#search=%27DHT11+datasheet%27))
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sXhT.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>

#define MAXTIMINGS  85
#define DHTPIN      15  //DHT connect to TxD
int dht11_dat[5] ={0,0,0,0,0};//store DHT11 data

void read_dht11_dat()
{
    uint8_t laststate = HIGH;
    uint8_t counter = 0;
    uint8_t j = 0,i;
    float f;//fahrenheit

    dht11_dat[0] = dht11_dat[1] = dht11_dat[2] = dht11_dat[3] = dht11_dat[4] = 0;

    //pull pin down to send start signal
    pinMode( DHTPIN, OUTPUT );
    digitalWrite( DHTPIN, LOW );
    delay( 18 );
    //pull pin up and wait for sensor response
    digitalWrite( DHTPIN, HIGH );
    delayMicroseconds( 40 );
    //prepare to read the pin
    pinMode( DHTPIN, INPUT );
    ***************************************************************
    //detect change and read data
    for ( i = 0; i < MAXTIMINGS; i++ ) { 
        counter = 0; 
        while ( digitalRead( DHTPIN ) == laststate ) { 
            counter++; 
            delayMicroseconds( 1 ); 
            if ( counter == 255 ) { break; }
        }

        laststate = digitalRead( DHTPIN ); 
        if ( counter == 255 ) break; 
         //ignore first 3 transitions if ( (i >= 4) && (i % 2 == 0) )
        {
            //shove each bit into the storage bytes
            dht11_dat[j / 8] <<= 1; 
            if ( counter > 16 )dht11_dat[j / 8] |= 1;
            j++;
        }
    }
    **************************************************************************
    //check we read 40 bits(8bit x 5) +verify checksum in the last byte
    //print it out if data is good
    if ( (j >= 40) &&
         (dht11_dat[4] == ( (dht11_dat[0] + dht11_dat[1] + dht11_dat[2] + dht11_dat[3]) & 0xFF) ) )
    {
        f = dht11_dat[2] * 9. / 5. + 32;
        printf( "Humidity = %d.%d %% Temperature = %d.%d C (%.1f F)\n",
            dht11_dat[0], dht11_dat[1], dht11_dat[2], dht11_dat[3], f );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "Data not good, skip\n" );
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    if ( wiringPiSetup() == -1 )
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Can't init wiringPi: %s\n",strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    print_info();
    while ( 1 )
    {
        read_dht11_dat();
        delay(1000);//wait ls to refresh
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Why not ask the person who has written the code?

Answer (score 0):

The `while ( digitalRead( DHTPIN ) == laststate )` checks for a digital state of the pin for up to 255us, then breaks out of the outer for loop if it didn't find a change. I don't think the number 255 is significant, it's just some upper timeout limit. It's a crude hack used instead of properly using on-chip hardware timers with input capture.

Apparently the counter is meaningful for the algorithm too, so it seems to be measuring duty cycle of a PWM pulse or such. Again, in a very crude way.

I suppose hardware timers might not be easily accessible on a Rasp PI "PC in disguise" - this whole thing would be much easier and prettier with a bare metal microcontroller.

The line `//ignore first 3 transitions if ( (i >= 4) && (i % 2 == 0) )` is code smell. Was this commented out on purpose or is it just some remains of someone's debugging attempts?

The lines

```
dht11_dat[j / 8] <<= 1; 
if ( counter > 16 )dht11_dat[j / 8] |= 1;
```

just fills up a bitfield/byte array with ones or zeroes depending on if the counter was larger than 16us or not. The shift moves the previous data up, then the LSB is either set to 1 or remain 0.

Comment: it might be easier and prettier on bare metal, but you probably couldn't program it in Python ;) I get the impression that the Pi C examples provided with many sensor devices have just been hacked up as an afterthought -- for better or worse, Python remains the staple diet of Pi hackers.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I kind of get it ! Also, I made a mistake.//ignore first 3 transitions if ( (i >= 4) && (i % 2 == 0) )  This part is a code line. I still have two questions. 1.Why do I have to ignore 3 transitions 2.What exactly do in this code ? Could you give me an example ?"if ( counter > 30 )dht11_dat[j / 8] |= 1;

Comment: @MasakiImai There is no telling why the code was there without knowing the hardware. If the person who wrote the code didn't explain why in comments, you'll have to bring out the scope and check the signal yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The program sets a pin high for while to signal the device to transmit. The device transmits 40 bits of data, with a '1' and a '0' being signalled by the length of time the pin is held high. The program just samples the pin state until it's detected 85 edge transitions (which is just a few more that there should actually be), or until 255 usec elapses without an edge. The number of loop cycles between edges is used to determine whether to shift a '1' or a '0' in the data array.

The data is divided into five bytes, with the last byte being a checksum from the previous four.

The speed of communication is perhaps too fast for loop-sampling like this, and I get the impression that some of the parameters in the program might have been arrived at by trial-and-error. That's a reasonably safe thing to do on stock Pi, at least of a particular model, since there's so little variation between them.

Nevertheless, I can't help thinking that a better approach would be to trap the rising-edge interrupt provided in the GPIO firmware, followed by a single sample after a fixed delay. Just do this 40 times until all 40 bits have been read. I guess you'd need some back-out in case communication were lost.